# CALL failed: (1305) PROCEDURE does not existStore failed

Tags: php, sql, syntax

Could someone explain me what is the cause of: CALL failed: (1305) PROCEDURE does not exist
I am a newbie, so my knowledge on the subject is not so good. As far as I know it is because of syntax error. However The syntax should be fine as it passes 8 parametres (2 of wich I hardcoded to make sure they did not have any type casting issues). If someone smarter than me could tell me why am I banging my head in the wall with this, I would apreciate it.

CALL failed: (1305) PROCEDURE tk2030.tase_kuutio does not existStore failed: (1305) PROCEDURE tk2030.tase_kuutio does not exist

PHP call:

```
$fetch_params['klaji'] = 0;
$fetch_params['plaji'] = 0;
//$fetch_params['isanta_rivi'] = 1;

        if (!$mysqli->multi_query('CALL tase_kuutio(' .$fetch_params['tilikausi']. ',' .$fetch_params['kvartaali']. ',' .$fetch_params['kuukausi']. ',' .$fetch_params['kpaikka']. ',' .$fetch_params['projekti'].  ',' . $fetch_params['klaji']. ',' .$fetch_params['plaji']. ',' .$fetch_params['isanta_rivi']. ');')) {
            echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
        }
```

Here us the procedure tase_kuutio is the one getting the error.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS tase_kuutio//
/*
    Funktio taseen summien laskemiseen
    Parametrit :
        tilikausi_id - Käsiteltävän tilikauden määrittävä tunniste. Pakollinen tieto.
        kvartaali_id - Käsiteltävän kvartaalin määrittävä tunniste (ei enää käytössä). Arvo 0 tarkoittaa, että kvartaalia ei ole valittu.
        kuukausi_id - Käsiteltävän kuukauden määrittävä tunniste. Arvo 0 tarkoittaa, että kuukautta ei ole valittu.
        dimensioiden id:t (kpaikka_id,projekti_id,klaji_id,plaji_id) - Määrittävät huomioitavat dimensioiden arvot. Arvo -1 tarkoittaa, että kyseistä dimensioita ei ole yrityksellä käytössä.
*/
CREATE PROCEDURE tase_kuutio (IN tilikausi_id INT , IN kvartaali_id INT , IN kuukausi_id INT , IN kpaikka_id INT , IN projekti_id INT , IN klaji_id INT , IN plaji_id INT , IN isanta INT)
BEGIN 
    /*
        Muuttujat korjattuja klaji_id, plaji_id varten. Näitä arvoja käytetään WHERE-ehdossa ja ne päätellään parametreinä annettujen id:den perusteella.
    */
    DECLARE k_klaji_id , k_plaji_id SMALLINT;
    /*
        Muuttujat, jotka sisältävät taseen laskennan ehtolausekkeet.
        isanta_ehto -   Ehtolauseke, joka määrittää lasketaanko summat kaikille riveille, vai suoraan jonkin tietyn otsikon alle sijoittuville riveille. Vastaa käyttöliittymässä toiminnallisuutta, jossa 
                        +-näppäintä painamalla saadaan esille summat, joista rivin summa koostuu
        nyk_summa_ehto - Jakson muutoksen summien laskemiseen käytettävä ehto. Mikäli jakson muutos on yhtä suuri kuin kumulatiivinen summa, on muutos = kumul. summa - alkava saldo
        nyk_kumul_ehto - Käsiteltävän jakson kumulatiivisten summien laskemiseen käytettävä ehto.
        e_kumul_ehto - Alkavan taseen summien laskemiseen käytettävä ehto. Eli hakee summat käsiteltävän kauden alussa (eli edellisen kauden lopullisen kumulatiivisen summan).
    */
    DECLARE isanta_ehto , nyk_summa_ehto , nyk_kumul_ehto , e_kumul_ehto VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT '';

    /*Määritetään käsiteltävä tilikausi. Pakollinen ehto.*/
    SET nyk_summa_ehto = CONCAT( 'tilikausi = ' , tilikausi_id);

    /*
        Alla määritetään korjatut ehdot klajille ja plajille. Korjaus tarvitsee tehdä, sillä yritykset joille ei näytetä jompaakumpaa tai kumpaakaan
        näistä dimensioista, antavat id:nä arvon -1, joka ei ole validi ehto. Tässä tapauksessa arvoksi muutetaan 0, joka merkitsee, ettei dimension arvoa rajoiteta.
    */
    IF klaji_id=-1 THEN
        SET k_klaji_id=0;
    ELSE
        SET k_klaji_id=klaji_id;
    END IF;

    IF plaji_id=-1 THEN
        SET k_plaji_id=0;
    ELSE
        SET k_plaji_id=plaji_id;
    END IF;

    /*
        Alla määritetään 
    */
    IF kuukausi_id > 0 THEN
        SET nyk_summa_ehto = CONCAT( nyk_summa_ehto , ' AND tilikk <= ' , kuukausi_id);
    ELSEIF kvartaali_id > 0 THEN
        SET nyk_summa_ehto = CONCAT( nyk_summa_ehto , ' AND kvartaali <= ' , kvartaali_id);
    END IF;
    /*Määritetään käsiteltävä tilikausi. Pakollinen ehto.*/
    SET nyk_kumul_ehto = CONCAT( 'tilikausi = ' , tilikausi_id);

    IF kuukausi_id > 0 THEN
        SET nyk_kumul_ehto = CONCAT( nyk_kumul_ehto , ' AND tilikk <= ' , kuukausi_id);
    ELSEIF kvartaali_id > 0 THEN
        SET nyk_kumul_ehto = CONCAT( nyk_kumul_ehto , ' AND kvartaali <= ' , kvartaali_id);
    END IF;
    /*
        Määritetään käsiteltävä tilikausi. Pakollinen ehto.
        Alkavaa saldoa laskettaessa käsiteltävä tilikausi on kuitenkin edellinen tilikausi.
    */
    SET e_kumul_ehto = CONCAT( 'tilikausi = ' , tilikausi_id - 1);

    /*
        Alla luodaan väliaikaiset taulut, joihin kerätään kunkin taseen sarakkeen arvot ennen niiden yhdistämistä
    */
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_1 (
        rivi INT ,
        rivi_id INT ,
        isanta_rivi INT ,
        taso INT ,
        lihavointi INT ,
        tili_rivi INT ,
        otsikko VARCHAR(100) ,
        selite VARCHAR(100) ,
        summa DECIMAL(10,2) ,
        PRIMARY KEY USING HASH (rivi)
    ) ENGINE = MEMORY;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_2 (
        rivi INT ,
        kumul DECIMAL(10,2) ,
        PRIMARY KEY USING HASH (rivi)
    ) ENGINE = MEMORY;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_3 (
        rivi INT ,
        e_kumul DECIMAL(10,2) ,
        PRIMARY KEY USING HASH (rivi)
    ) ENGINE = MEMORY;

    /*
        Määritetään isanta_ehto, eli annetaan sen rivin id, jonka alariveille summat halutaan laskea. Mikäli arvo on 0, lasketaan arvot kaikille riveille.
    */
    IF isanta > 0 THEN
        SET isanta_ehto = CONCAT('AND t.isanta_rivi = ' , isanta);
    END IF;


    /*
        Lasketaan tauluun tbl_1 jakson muutokset. etumerkki-sarakkeen arvo määrittää, täytyykö pääkirjalta haettujen summien merkkiä kääntää vai ei.
    */
    SET @stmt = CONCAT( 'INSERT INTO tbl_1 (rivi,rivi_id,isanta_rivi,taso,lihavointi,tili_rivi,otsikko,selite,summa)
                        SELECT  t.rivi , t.rivi_id , t.isanta_rivi , t.taso , t.lihavointi , t.rivi_tyyppi , t.otsikko , t.selite , 
                                CASE etumerkki
                                    WHEN 0 THEN -1 * IFNULL(SUM(s.summa),0.00) 
                                    ELSE IFNULL(SUM(s.summa),0.00) 
                                END AS summa
                        FROM tase_mem t
                                LEFT JOIN kuutio_paakirja s ON s.tili = t.tili
                        WHERE   ' , nyk_summa_ehto , ' 
                                AND s.kpaikka_id = ' , kpaikka_id , ' AND s.projekti_id = ' , projekti_id , ' AND s.klaji_id = ' , k_klaji_id , ' AND s.plaji_id = ' , k_plaji_id , ' '  , isanta_ehto , '
                        GROUP BY t.rivi , t.rivi_id , t.taso , t.lihavointi , t.rivi_tyyppi , t.etumerkki , t.otsikko , t.selite;');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt;
    EXECUTE stmt;

    /*
        Lasketaan tauluun tbl_2 jakson kumulatiiviset summat. etumerkki-sarakkeen arvo määrittää, täytyykö pääkirjalta haettujen summien merkkiä kääntää vai ei.
    */
    SET @stmt = CONCAT( 'INSERT INTO tbl_2(rivi,kumul)
                        SELECT  t.rivi , 
                                CASE etumerkki
                                    WHEN 0 THEN -1 * IFNULL(SUM(s.summa),0.00) 
                                    ELSE IFNULL(SUM(s.summa),0.00) 
                                END AS kumul
                        FROM tase_mem t
                                LEFT JOIN kuutio_paakirja s ON s.tili = t.tili
                        WHERE   ' , nyk_kumul_ehto , ' 
                                AND s.kpaikka_id = ' , kpaikka_id , ' AND s.projekti_id = ' , projekti_id , ' AND s.klaji_id = ' , k_klaji_id , ' AND s.plaji_id = ' , k_plaji_id , ' ' , isanta_ehto , '
                        GROUP BY t.rivi , t.rivi_id , t.taso , t.lihavointi , t.rivi_tyyppi , t.etumerkki , t.otsikko , t.selite;');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt;
    EXECUTE stmt;       

    /*
        Lasketaan tauluun tbl_3 alkavat saldot. etumerkki-sarakkeen arvo määrittää, täytyykö pääkirjalta haettujen summien merkkiä kääntää vai ei.
    */
    SET @stmt = CONCAT( 'INSERT INTO tbl_3(rivi,e_kumul)
                        SELECT  t.rivi , 
                                CASE etumerkki
                                    WHEN 0 THEN -1 * IFNULL(SUM(s.summa),0.00) 
                                    ELSE IFNULL(SUM(s.summa),0.00) 
                                END AS kumul
                        FROM tase_mem t
                                LEFT JOIN kuutio_paakirja s ON s.tili = t.tili
                        WHERE   ' , e_kumul_ehto , ' 
                                AND s.kpaikka_id = ' , kpaikka_id , ' AND s.projekti_id = ' , projekti_id , ' AND s.klaji_id = ' , k_klaji_id , ' AND s.plaji_id = ' , k_plaji_id , ' ' , isanta_ehto , '
                        GROUP BY t.rivi , t.rivi_id , t.taso , t.lihavointi , t.rivi_tyyppi , t.etumerkki , t.otsikko , t.selite;');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt;
    EXECUTE stmt;       

    /*
        Yhdistetään eri sarakkeet yhdeksi tauluksi
            1.sarake on alkava saldo taulusta tbl_3
            2.sarake on jakson muutos, joka saadaan suoraan taulusta tbl_1 tai mikäli se on yhtä suuri kuin kumulatiivinen summa, tbl_1- ja tbl_3-taulujen arvojen erotuksena
            3.sarake on jakson kumulatiivinen summa taulusta tbl_2
    */
    SELECT  t1.rivi , t1.rivi_id , t1.isanta_rivi , t1.taso , t1.lihavointi , t1.tili_rivi , t1.otsikko , t1.selite ,
            IFNULL(t3.e_kumul,0.00) av_saldo ,
            IF(t1.summa = t2.kumul , t1.summa - IFNULL(t3.e_kumul,0.00) , t1.summa) summa , 
            t2.kumul kumul
    FROM tbl_1 t1
        LEFT JOIN tbl_2 t2 ON t2.rivi = t1.rivi
        LEFT JOIN tbl_3 t3 ON t3.rivi = t1.rivi
    ORDER BY t1.rivi_id asc , t1.rivi asc;

    DROP TABLE tbl_1;
    DROP TABLE tbl_2;
    DROP TABLE tbl_3;

END//

delimiter ;

/*CALL tase_kuutio(4,0,0,0,0,0,0,1);*/
```

Comment: As I see you call the procedure tase_kuutio from php code, while your procedure's name is tuloslaskelma_kuutio. Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: If you scroll down there is also tase_kuutio. I will remove the tuloslaskelma part from shown code to ease reading

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Is it possible that the user calling your procedure from php does not have necessary privileges to execute it?

Comment: No, it worked previosly without (k_klaji_id , k_plaji_id) after adding clauses (SQL-side) for them it stopped working. I can see that they are being sent to to the CALL, but it gives out the error. Also I have all the admin rights and it is being run on the test server...